# tee: invalid option -- 'f'

Tags: tee

```
sudo echo «deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx» \  | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_s
```

tee: invalid option -- 'f'

How to fix issue that I have while trying to 'add nginx repository'?

Answer (score 3):

I presume, you are following the Ubuntu package install from [`here`](http://nginx.org/en/linux_packages.html#Ubuntu).

There are multiple issues in your command line:

```
sudo echo «deb http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx» \ 
   | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list \
   curl -fsSL https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_s
```

- `«` and `»` are invalid symbols in this context. I presume, you wanted to use `"`
- The `curl` instruction is missing a separation from the `tee` command. This is why the `-f` from `curl -fsSL` is used by `tee` - adding a `;` or `&&` between `tee` and `curl` would fix this, but the `curl` command does not make sens at all. It try's to fetch a key and write it to `stdou`, but the URL is invalid.

Try it as described on the homepage of Nginx:

- Install the key first

  ```
  curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor \
    | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null
  ```
- Add the repository to `apt`

  ```
  echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
  http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu `lsb_release -cs` nginx" \
    | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
  ```
- Update the database

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```
- Install nginx

  ```
  sudo apt install nginx
  ```